# How can I subscribe to a channel and then do something else without blocking?

Tags: c, asynchronous, redis, publish-subscribe, nonblocking

I am using redis pub/sub to do some real-time processing.

In subscribe ends, I want to subscribe to a specified channel, then do some other computations. I am under the imporession that if I send a `subscribe` command to server, it will block the code.

So how can I do something else, and when the subscribe message arrives, I process that via a callback handler?

Answer (score 1):

You need two different connections to do that. This is was a design choice because when you SUBSCRIBE / PSUBSCRIBE, actually the connection semantics changes from Request-Response to Push-style, so it is not suitable to run commands without implementing a more complex semantics like the one, for example, of the IMAP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

The first point is to dedicate a Redis connection to the subscriptions. Once SUBSCRIBE or PUSBSCRIBE has been applied on a connection, only subscription related commands can be done. So in a C program, you need at least one connection for your subscription(s), and one connection to do anything else with Redis.

Then you need to also find a way to handle those two connections from the C program. Several solutions are possible. For instance:

- use multi-threading, and dedicate a thread to the connection responsible of subscriptions. On reception on a new event, the dedicated thread should post a message to your main application thread, which will activate a callback.
- use non-blocking and asynchronous API. Hiredis comes with event loop adapters. You need an event loop to handle the connections to Redis (including the one dedicated to subscription). Upon reception of a publication event, the associated callback will be directly triggered by the event loop. Here is [an example of subscription with hiredis and libevent](https://gist.github.com/dspezia/5459774).